# Google Maps and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, google-maps

I  am looking for a way to visualize data from Postgres in Google Maps, but I have only figured out how to do this for Markers. 
I am using PHP to retrieve the data in JSON, which I then request from Google Maps, but I can only find examples for doing this with point data.

```
  var geocoderFunction = function () { 
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': road[index] }, 
           function (results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                 });
           }             
   }
```

Comment: Look at [DataLayers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer). There are full code samples there for loading, styling and interacting with GeoJSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question very well.

If you are asking how to display a line with the Google Maps API i think that you should check the documentation about [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=es#Polyline) or check the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=es) like [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple?hl=es).

Comment: Yes this is i want to make but i have a problem with cordinates i have in 4120 system and i try to convert in 4326 
with this query 'ALTER TABLE my_table
    ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point,4326) USING ST_Transform(geom,4326);'
but i take the cordinates as 4120 what i can make because the google maps use 4326 system.

Comment: That's a different question. Check this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70668/4177 or open a new question. As mark this as resolved if it solves your first question

Comment: Yes Francisco is resolved how i can this question as resolved

Comment: @vagelis click the check mark in my answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers